# HTML show list of files if condition is met

Tags: html, directory, conditional-statements

I have a server in which 3 files are created every day and throughout the day, a new version of them is uploaded every 5 minutes.

The name of the files are

```
Joe_#date#_map.html
George_#date#_map.html
Tom_#date#_map.html
```

With #date# being in the format ddmmyy.

I'd like a way of only showing 3 links to the 3 files of the current day. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: The fix will depend on the web server you're using and how much you're willing to code. Please provide environment details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
//  Define the name prefixes to use.
var NAMES = ['Joe', 'George', 'Tom'];

function createLinks() {
    // Get current day, month, and year
    var today = new Date(),
        dd = today.getDate(),
        mm = today.getMonth() + 1,
        yy = today.getYear() % 100;

    // Pad with 0s
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    //  Create the string.
    var dateStr = '' + dd + mm + yy;

    //  Create each image.
    for (var i = 0; i < NAMES.length; i++) {
        var linkEl = document.createElement('a');
        linkEl.innerHTML = NAMES[i];
        linkEl.href = NAMES[i] + '_' + dateStr + '_map.html';

        document.body.appendChild(linkEl) // Or wherever you want them to go.
    }
}
createLinks();
```

Note that this will place the links at the bottom of the document.

Also keep in mind this is subject to the client computer's timezone (it might be tomorrow for them before your server). A safer method would be to render the links on the server side.